# Listen to angular event click on webbrowser

Tags: angular, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a winform application.
On the form I have webrowser control that the URI is angular app.
I want that when I click on button(on app angular in webbrowser) the event on form in winform is raise.

How can I do it?

I saw an example of a code that lets you listen to an event in the DOM and I need something just like listening to the click of a button :

**Listener class:**

```
public class DOMListener
{
    public event Action DOMChanged;

    private WebBrowser Browser;

    public DOMListener(WebBrowser webbrowser)
    {
        this.Browser = webbrowser;
        this.Browser.ObjectForScripting = this;
        this.Browser.DocumentCompleted += OnDOMLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDOMLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement script = this.Browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
        script.InnerHtml = "function listenToDOM() { document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) { window.external.DOMUpdate() }); }";
        this.Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].AppendChild(script);
        this.Browser.Document.InvokeScript("listenToDOM");
    }

    public void DOMUpdate()
    {
        if (this.DOMChanged != null) this.DOMChanged.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**On Form.cs:**

```
Public void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {

            this.Listener = new DOMListener(this.webBrowser1);
            this.Listener.DOMChanged += this.OnDOMChanged;
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:5050/Api/IESAngularDemo/"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    void OnDOMChanged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": DOM changed");
    }
```

Comment: You should add more detail to the question, what did you try, what didnt work, how did you change your code, did it lead to a different result.... and so on

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I want help if you can do such a thing and how to do it